# Convert CMYK to RGB without changing the color

Tags: python, image, opencv, python-imaging-library

there! How can you convert an CMYK image in RGB image without changing the color of the picture?
Current result:

```
from PIL import Image
image = Image.open('img.jpg').convert('RGB')
image.save('out.jpg')
```

I am using this picture:
[image]

After conversion, I get the following result:
[image]

Comment: I am happy with your result

Comment: https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/83985/photoshop-how-to-change-from-rgb-to-cmyk-without-any-color-loss

Comment: "I am using this picture" -- If I download that, ImageMagick tells me it's a 3 channel image in sRGB colourspace...

Comment: @DanMašek, I can't attach a CMYK image, but you can take any other image and do the same conversion.

Answer (score 1):

Try using ImageCms from PIL to do the profile conversion:

```
from PIL import Image
from PIL import ImageCms
import numpy

img_path = 'input.png'

def cmyk_to_rgb(cmyk_img):
    img = Image.open(cmyk_img)
    if img.mode == "CMYK":
        img = ImageCms.profileToProfile(img, "Color Profiles\\USWebCoatedSWOP.icc", "Color Profiles\\sRGB_Color_Space_Profile.icm", outputMode="RGB")
    return numpy.array(img)

orig_img = cmyk_to_rgb(str(img_path))
pilImage = Image.fromarray(orig_img)
pilImage.save('output.png')
```

Comment: Why are you converting the image to `numpy.array`, returning that, and then converting back to `PIL.Image.Image`?